# Why is 悪いわさ話 marked with を in 「悪いわさ話を聞かれてしまった」?

Tags: particles, passive-form

I came across the following sentence in [another post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/19585/51280):

> 悪いわさ話を聞かれてしまった。

I'm assuming わさ is slang for 噂, so that the sentence becomes

> 悪い噂話を聞かれてしまった。

**Question:** Since 聞く ("to hear") is taking the passive tense ("to be heard"), and the 悪い噂話 ("bad rumor") is the thing being heard, shouldn't 悪い噂話 have the が (or は) particle attached to it instead of the を particle? For example in English:

> A *bad rumor* was heard.

It seems to me "bad rumor" is the subject and not the direct object of this sentence.

Comment: These might help: [Passive form - The exact difference between を and が](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11025/43676), [How is the passive form used with を?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/69169/43676)